# Is there a particular name for the set of all relations?

Tags: terminology, relations

I know that a relation on a set $S$ is a subset $R \subseteq S \times S$ such that for all $(s,s') \in S \times S$, $(s,s') \in R$ iff $sRs'$, therefore the set $T$ of all relations on $S$ is the set $\mathcal{P}(S \times S)$ of all subsets of $S \times S$, in other words $T=\mathcal{P}(S \times S)$.

I'm wondering if there is a particular name for "the set of all relations", something condensed, less wordy, like 'the omnirelational set'.

Side question: Say $T^0=T$. Is there anything interesting that comes from considering $T^1=\mathcal{P}(T^0 \times T^0)$ or furthermore $T^{n+1}=\mathcal{P}(T^n \times T^n)$?

Comment: I don't know any special name for $\mathcal P(S\times S)$. I also don't recall any occasion where I felt that there should be such name.

Comment: I agree. In fact I think that, if anything, using a special name for $\mathcal{P}(S \times S)$ would just be a barrier to other people from understanding what you're talking about (not a good thing).

Comment: Regarding your side question: OK so $T$ is a set, $T^1$ is the set of relations on $T$, $T^2$ is the set of relations on relations on $T$,  and so on. Since it is often useful, given relations $R,R' \in T^1$, to know for instance that $R \subset R'$, I guess we can say that $T^2$ has at least one interesting element. Namely, $\subset \in T^2$.

Comment: $\text{Hom}_{\text{Rel}}(S, S)$.

Comment: This set, with the composition of binary relation, has a structure  of monoid which I call it binary relation monoid :)